# storing spring boot sessions into hazelcast

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-session

I have hazelcast server started on my local computer where I'm trying to store sessions from spring boot application using spring-session-hazelcast:3.1.1
config:

```
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession(sessionMapName = "authorization:session", saveMode = SaveMode.ALWAYS, flushMode = FlushMode.IMMEDIATE, maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 1800)
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");

        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

}
```

by this approach hazelcast server needs some dependencies (spring-session-core, spring-session-hazelcast ...) on server side (de)serialization which I want to avoid.

I think converting MapSession object
into String json and storing it into hazelcast will work without any extra dependencies but only way I found to do this is registering custom serializer

```
    public class HazelcastSerializer implements StreamSerializer<MapSession> {

    private static final int SERIALIZER_TYPE_ID = 12313121;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public HazelcastSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@Nonnull ObjectDataOutput out, @Nonnull MapSession object) throws IOException {
        out.writeString(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public MapSession read(@Nonnull ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(in, MapSession.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getTypeId() {
        return SERIALIZER_TYPE_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        StreamSerializer.super.destroy();
    }
}


    SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig();
serializerConfig.setImplementation(new HazelcastSerializer(new ObjectMapper())).setTypeClass(MapSession.class);
clientConfig.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);
```

but even if I create custom serializer it needs to be registered also on server side which means I also have to add dependencies

any solution?